# PyTorch Slow Batch matrix multiplication on GPU

Tags: python, pytorch

I am using Batch Matrix Multiplication on 2 3d tensors of sizes `(100 , 128 , 128 )` each.

```
import torch
a = torch.randn(100,128,128)
b = torch.randn(100,128,128)

import time

t0 = time.time()
torch.bmm(a,b)
print(time.time() - t0)
```

> 0.03233695030212402

Now if i do the same thing on GPU it takes a lot longer

```
a = a.cuda()
b = b.cuda()
t0 = time.time()
torch.bmm(a,b)
print(time.time() - t0)
```

> 30.574532985687256

Why does it take so long to solve on GPU?

I have a GTX 1050 Ti 4GB

And processor core i3-6100 3.7Ghz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**GPU:**

*30.57* secs is the total time taken by following steps:

1. CPU launches kernels* on the device (GPU)
2. CPU allocates memory on GPU
3. CPU copies input data to GPU
4. CPU launches kernels on GPU to process the input data
5. CPU copies output results to itself

*Kernel is a serial code which is a small part of the original code.

**CPU**

Whereas, *0.0323* secs is the total time taken by either:

1. Intra-CPU communications
2. CPU and main memory communications

These are very fast and they also have to execute fewer commands to get work done.

**Conclusion**

Hence it's a trade-off between the complexity of the commands (CPU commands being more complex) and speed-up due to parellelism and simpler nature of commands (GPU can fire more parallel threads and they are much simpler in nature).

If there were more computations to be done, then GPU speed-up would overwhelm the extra time taken for CPU-GPU communications.

Comment: Turns out my GPU was busy with other things and initialization of variables and results on cuda was taking time. All i had to do was just call `torch.cuda.synchronize()` to fix the timing. https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/slow-batch-matrix-multiplication-on-gpu/11358